# python for loop with range()

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range

For some reason I've hell of time trying to wrap my head around looping with ranges.

The code:

```
# inefficient way to compute primes with "filter"
nums = range(2, 100)
for i in range(2, 8):
    """Sieve of Eratosthenes:
        Leave the element in the list if it is equal to "i",
        or if it leaves a non-zero remainder when divided by "i".
        """
    # (x % i returns either zero or non-zero, 0 -> False, non-0 -> True)
    nums = filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i != 0, nums)

print nums
```

Producing this output (i.e. primes up to 100):

```
[
 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17,
 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41,
 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67,
 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97
]
```

This is the second question regarding this I've asked here and I cannot for the life of me figure out how this works. Can someone explain, step by step (preferably so that it can be visualized) what's happening here exactly. For example why doesn't `4` get printed as a prime? Since x == i (i.e. 4==4) or x % i --> True of False equals True.

Comment: You might want to try something like http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the fact that `nums` is getting filtered on every iteration. So, on the first iteration, all numbers for which x % 2 is not 0 - which includes 4 - are filtered out.

If you put an extra `print nums` within the loop, after the filter, you would see this more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code utilizes the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/) method to identify prime numbers up to 100. It initializes a list named `nums` containing numbers ranging from 2 to 99. Then, it executes a loop over the numbers 2 to 7. Within each iteration, a filtration process takes place using the `filter` function alongside a lambda expression. This operation eliminates numbers from `nums` that are divisible by the current value of `i` or identical to `i` itself. Following each iteration, `nums` is updated to retain solely the remaining prime numbers. Numbers like 4 are dropped from the final result as they are recognized as composite during the filtration procedure due to their divisibility by 2.